# Finding kth smallest element using insertion sort

Tags: c, insertion-sort

I was trying to write code to find kth smallest element using insertion sort but i get runtime error at my code .
We are given number of queries(say n) and k (kth smallest number to find out) at first line . Then we  are given n numbers , if we encounter -1 , we need to print kth smallest number which we have encountered so far (except previous -1s) .

i tried using to [implement](http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/archives/10379) after little editing according to question .

(i am not posting the code since its very long enough for anyone to read through & this question is not homework)
Can anyone please tell the edit required ?

Okay i post my code :-

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define ARRAY_SIZE(arr) sizeof(arr)/sizeof(arr[0])

/* just add elements to test */
/* NOTE: A sorted array results in skewed tree */
int ele[] = { 20, 8, 22, 4, 12, 10, 14 };

/* same alias */
typedef struct node_t node_t;

/* Binary tree node */
struct node_t
{
    int data;

    node_t* left;
    node_t* right;
};

/* simple stack that stores node addresses */
typedef struct stack_t stack_t;

/* initial element always NULL, uses as sentinal */
struct stack_t
{
    node_t*  base[ARRAY_SIZE(ele) + 1];
    int      stackIndex;
};

/* pop operation of stack */
node_t *pop(stack_t *st)
{
    node_t *ret = NULL;

    if( st && st->stackIndex > 0 )
    {
        ret = st->base[st->stackIndex];
        st->stackIndex--;
    }

    return ret;
}

/* push operation of stack */
void push(stack_t *st, node_t *node)
{
    if( st )
    {
        st->stackIndex++;
        st->base[st->stackIndex] = node;
    }
}

/* Iterative insertion
   Recursion is least preferred unless we gain something
*/
node_t *insert_node(node_t *root, node_t* node)
{
    /* A crawling pointer */
    node_t *pTraverse = root;
    node_t *currentParent = root;

    // Traverse till appropriate node
    while(pTraverse)
    {
        currentParent = pTraverse;

        if( node->data < pTraverse->data )
        {
            /* left subtree */
            pTraverse = pTraverse->left;
        }
        else
        {
            /* right subtree */
            pTraverse = pTraverse->right;
        }
    }

    /* If the tree is empty, make it as root node */
    if( !root )
    {
        root = node;
    }
    else if( node->data < currentParent->data )
    {
        /* Insert on left side */
        currentParent->left = node;
    }
    else
    {
        /* Insert on right side */
        currentParent->right = node;
    }

    return root;
}

/* Elements are in an array. The function builds binary tree */
node_t* binary_search_tree(node_t *root, int keys[], int const size)
{
    int iterator;
    node_t *new_node = NULL;

    for(iterator = 0; iterator < size; iterator++)
    {
        new_node = (node_t *)malloc( sizeof(node_t) );

        /* initialize */
        new_node->data   = keys[iterator];
        new_node->left   = NULL;
        new_node->right  = NULL;

        /* insert into BST */
        root = insert_node(root, new_node);
    }

    return root;
}

node_t *k_smallest_element_inorder(stack_t *stack, node_t *root, int k)
{
    stack_t *st = stack;
    node_t *pCrawl = root;

    /* move to left extremen (minimum) */
    while( pCrawl )
    {
        push(st, pCrawl);
        pCrawl = pCrawl->left;
    }

    /* pop off stack and process each node */
    while( pCrawl = pop(st) )
    {
        /* each pop operation emits one element
           in the order
        */
        if( !--k )
        {
            /* loop testing */
            st->stackIndex = 0;
            break;
        }

        /* there is right subtree */
        if( pCrawl->right )
        {
            /* push the left subtree of right subtree */
            pCrawl = pCrawl->right;
            while( pCrawl )
            {
                push(st, pCrawl);
                pCrawl = pCrawl->left;
            }

            /* pop off stack and repeat */
        }
    }

    /* node having k-th element or NULL node */
    return pCrawl;
}

/* Driver program to test above functions */
int main(void)
{
    int n,k,elec=0,tmp;
    scanf("%d",&n);
    scanf("%d",&k);
    while (n--) {
          scanf("%d",&tmp);
          if (tmp!=-1) {
             ele[elec]=tmp;
             elec++;
          } else {
    node_t* root = NULL;
    stack_t stack = { {0}, 0 };
    node_t *kNode = NULL;


    /* Creating the tree given in the above diagram */
    root = binary_search_tree(root, ele, ARRAY_SIZE(ele));

    kNode = k_smallest_element_inorder(&stack, root, k);

    if( kNode )
    {
        printf("%d\n",kNode->data);
    }
    }}
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: So you don't want to show the code that throws a runtime error... How do you think anybody can guess what goes on???

Comment: Whenever you get a runtime error or "crash", your first reaction should be to to run your program in a debugger. It will help you locate the place of the error, and also let you examine variables to see what might have caused the error.

Comment: As for not posting code, please see http://sscce.org/. If nothing else, you don't have to post _all_ the code, only the code that gives you trouble, plus whatever declarations needed to understand it.